# What is meant by ewma in ping statistics?

Tags: linux, ping

I was learning ping command implementation.

In that I had one doubt that is If I provide the -f or -A option, finally in statistics report, it have two extra field when compare to normal ping.

The extra fields are ipg and ewma.

I know what is the use of ipg and how to calculate.

But I don't know what is the use of ewma and how to calculate the ewma.

I was searching in google. But I didn't get the exact answer for that.

Can anyone please explain it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It stands for [Exponential Weight Moving Average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average).  It's a way of using a continuously-functioning output ( say a long-running fping/ping -f ) to get more-relevant results.  For a long-running ping, all old values no matter how old are still used for computing the min/max/avg but the use of EWMA gives you more relevant results for more recent pings.

**Update**

You are using apparently ping from the iputils package. The first visible change to the "standard" Ping is mdev. mdev gives the mean deviation, ie the standard deviation to the measured RTT to. Here is an excerpt from the source code to ipg and EWMA:

```
int ipg = (1000000 * (long long) tv.tv_sec + tv.tv_usec) / (ntransmitted-1);
printf ( "ipg / EWMA% d.% 03d /% d.% 03d ms"
ipg / 1000, ipg% 1000 rtt / 8000, (rtt / 8)% 1000);
```

Comment: This definition is already given in serverfault. But I am not able to understand that. Please give me more explanation.

Comment: @suresh I have already provided wiki link to elaborate my answer.

Comment: In that I am not able to match that formula to calculate in ping.

Comment: @suresh updated answer

Comment: What is rtt in calculation ?

Comment: @suresh : it stands for `round-trip travel`, [see](http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/round-trip-time) for more info.